# 2 lists of data with second list describing first, splitting the first in new lists

Tags: python, list

All values in list B are either 1.0 or 2.
I'm trying to go through `listA` (coded as "Time1) and depending on each corresponding value in `listB` (Coded as Channel1) sort each term into a new list.
aka:

```
A = [2.3, 4.3, 3.1] 
B = [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

becomes

```
P = [2.3, 3.1] 
Q = [4.3]
```

My current code for this is:

```
 a = 0

 for a in Time1:

     if Channel1[a] == 1:

         HistDetec1.append(Time1[a])

     if Channel1[a] == 2:

         HistDetec1.append(Time1[a])

     a = a + 1
```

But this doesn't work as it think that "a" is a float

```
list indices must be integers, not float
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes.

1 - First you are looping through the elements of A instead of indexes and try to use that elements as indexes at other list.

2 - You are appending in either case to the same list HistDetec1

3 - You try to increment index which for already do that

4 - You check equality of int values against float values

Try something like that:

```
for index in range(len(Time1)):
    if Channel1[index] == 1.0:
         HistDetec1.append(Time1[index])
    elif Channel1[index] == 2.0:
         HistDetec2.append(Time1[index])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: um, ok, I changed something completely unrelated and now this part stopped working even after I reverted it to exactly when it did work. 

"for index in range(len(Time1)):"   <- any idea why tuple object is not callable for this line?

Comment: Update, I fixed the problem using the ever reliable, turning it off then back on again method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> A = [2.3, 4.3, 3.1]
>>> B = [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]
>>> P = [t for i, t in enumerate(A) if B[i] == 1.0]
>>> P
[2.3, 3.1]
>>> Q = [t for i, t in enumerate(A) if B[i] == 2.0]
>>> Q
[4.3]
```

Or, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> P = [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 1.0]
>>> P
[2.3, 3.1]
>>> Q = [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 2.0]
>>> Q
[4.3]
```

Comment: What is "t" in this?

Comment: `enumerate` provides you with a tuple where the first element is the index and second one is the item itself. Here `i` is the index and `t` is the item at index `i` in list `A` i.e. for `i=0`, `t` would be `2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an integer there...

```
B = [1, 2, 1]
```

Or convert to integer before checking:

```
if Channel1[int(a)] == 1:
```